# How to group two or more fields using mongo aggregation to find the distincts

Tags: mongodb

My Appointment Document looks like this

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f25686c946376355468caab"),
    "status" : "approved",
    "slot" : ObjectId("5ee751ab85596308c0272fa2"),
    "student" : ObjectId("5eddc7d7cc5d3608c0393ce1"),
    "teacher" : ObjectId("5eccfd6d4f5d8d48ac567a5d"),
    "cost" : 49,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-01T13:04:44.696Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-01T13:20:36.164Z"),
    "decisionTime" : ISODate("2020-08-01T13:20:36.161Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f25687b946376355468caac"),
    "status" : "approved",
    "slot" : ObjectId("5ee751ab85596308c0272fa3"),
    "student" : ObjectId("5eddc7d7cc5d3608c0393ce1"),
    "teacher" : ObjectId("5eccfd6d4f5d8d48ac567a5d"),
    "cost" : 49,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-01T13:04:59.125Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-01T13:06:12.289Z"),
    "decisionTime" : ISODate("2020-08-01T13:06:12.288Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f2ad883f0971a0c3c7d6e6f"),
    "status" : "approved",
    "slot" : ObjectId("5ee751ab85596308c0272fa4"),
    "student" : ObjectId("5eddc7f4cc5d3608c0393ce3"),
    "teacher" : ObjectId("5eccfd6d4f5d8d48ac567a5d"),
    "cost" : 49,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-05T16:04:19.437Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-05T16:04:52.616Z"),
    "decisionTime" : ISODate("2020-08-05T16:04:52.615Z")
}]
```

I want to group total number of distinct student, total number of appointment, total cost on a particular date(createdAt) using mongo aggregation.
How do I get Distinct Student on a distinct Date

Expected Output :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "01-08-2020",
    "appointments": 2,
    "totalCost": 98,
    "totalStudents": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "05-08-2020",
    "appointments": 1,
    "totalCost": 49,
    "totalStudents": 1
  }
]
```

The problem here is that I want to find total number of distinct students

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Group by`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) `createdAt` field's day, month and year by using [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts) operator and just sum up `cost` field.

For getting distinct student fields, use the [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator and push it to a set while grouping and in the project stage just project the [`size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of that set.

Also format `createdAt` field [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) operator to your requirement `%d-%m-%Y`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateFromParts: {
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth: '$createdAt'
            },
            month: {
                $month: '$createdAt'
            },
            year: {
                $year: '$createdAt'
            }
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        $first: '$createdAt'
      },
      totalAppointments: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      totalCost: {
        $sum: '$cost'
      },
      students: {
        $addToSet: '$student'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: '$createdAt',
          format: '%d-%m-%Y'
        }
      },
      appointments: '$totalAppointments',
      totalCost: '$totalCost',
      totalStudents: {
        $size: '$students'
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Giving output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "05-08-2020",
    "appointments": 1,
    "totalCost": 49,
    "totalStudents": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "01-08-2020",
    "appointments": 2,
    "totalCost": 98,
    "totalStudents": 1
  }
]
```

[`MongoDb playground`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u2BAQ2kQfGJ)

Comment: It Gives me this error `$dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a string, found: date with value 2020-09-24T09:16:14.301Z` Actually I'm using mongoose and I want the total number of distinct students... like if two document contain same student Id then the `totalStudent` should be `1`

Comment: @ECSRoman Is your createdAt a `ISODate` or a string, in the question I see it as a string

Comment: It is saved as `createdAt:2020-10-16T07:06:07.814+00:00` in mongoDB ... I have updated the document in the question

Comment: I am getting different documents for the same date. I want to get one document for a single date like if the date is 16-10-2020 then I want total lessons on 16-10-2020, total distinct students on 16-10-2020 and total cost on 16-10-2020. Single document for a particular date

Comment: @ECSRoman Can you update the question with the data you are testing with

Comment: @ECSRoman updated the answer based on the updated data

Comment: If the Student id is repeating it should not count in total